# Eclipse Maven WebApp: "Cannot find symbol" on all dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly

(Several prints and snippets bellow)

Hello.
I'm having issues running "mvn install" on my Java project.
This Maven project that will be running on Wildfly 19 and has maven dependencies and one Project dependency.

But, every time I try to run "mvn install", it gives a "cannot find symbol" error for either maven dependencies or the project dependency.

I've tried several fixes but none have worked so far... Help would be very much appreciated.

**Cropped Error:**

[image]

**Eclipse Settings:**

[image: Web Deployment Assembly]

[image: Java Build Path Project Dependencies]

[image: Java Build Path Libraries]

[image: Java Build Path Order and Export]

**POM:**

```
  ...

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please do not post images of text or errors.

Comment: make sure the necessary packages are on the classpath or in the dependencies (in the right scope)